# how to solve This is related to npm not being able to find a file

Tags: npm, installation

`npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path F:\Remote Internship\two/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Remote Internship\two\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\WAQAR AHMAD\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-03-16T08_17_20_713Z-debug-0.log`

i could n't install npm